# SQL select distinct entity - union all - order by another entity's column

Tags: sql, hibernate, sql-order-by, distinct, union

I am using SQL to access an entity (Forslag), but would also like to sort using another entity's column (b.dato).

This is my initial SQL:

```
        select distinct ff.*
        from Forslag ff 
          inner join Forlag f on ff.forlag_id = f.forlag_id
          inner join LoggBehandling b on ff.forlag_id = b.forlag_id
          inner join Kontrollpanel p on f.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
        where b.status_id = 7

        union all

        select distinct ft.*
        from Forslag ft
          inner join Tidsskrift t on ft.tidsskrift_id = t.tidsskrift_id
          inner join LoggBehandling b on ft.tidsskrift_id = b.tidsskrift_id
          inner join Kontrollpanel p on t.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
        where  b.status_id = 7

        order by b.dato desc
```

Hibernate complains: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.`

I suspect I can't really add `b.dato` to select, as I assume this will have impact on the mapping:

```
        select distinct ff.*, b.dato
        from Forslag ff 
          inner join Forlag f on ff.forlag_id = f.forlag_id
          inner join LoggBehandling b on ff.forlag_id = b.forlag_id
          inner join Kontrollpanel p on f.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
        where b.status_id = 7

        union all

        select distinct ft.*, b.dato
        from Forslag ft
          inner join Tidsskrift t on ft.tidsskrift_id = t.tidsskrift_id
          inner join LoggBehandling b on ft.tidsskrift_id = b.tidsskrift_id
          inner join Kontrollpanel p on t.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
        where  b.status_id = 7

        order by b.dato desc
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure is HQL and not SQL???

The first: in HQL is not possible using UNION ALL but you must execute two distinct queries.

The second: in SQL when you use an order by when you have an UNION operation, you must apply ORDER BY to result table in this way:

The third: Why you use DISTINCT if you use UNION ALL?? Use UNION without ALL is the same thing of DISTINCT.

```
   select *
   from (
    select ff.*, b.dato as dato
    from Forslag ff 
      inner join Forlag f on ff.forlag_id = f.forlag_id
      inner join LoggBehandling b on ff.forlag_id = b.forlag_id
      inner join Kontrollpanel p on f.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
    where b.status_id = 7

    union all

    select distinct ft.*, b.dato
    from Forslag ft
      inner join Tidsskrift t on ft.tidsskrift_id = t.tidsskrift_id
      inner join LoggBehandling b on ft.tidsskrift_id = b.tidsskrift_id
      inner join Kontrollpanel p on t.uhrPuMote_id = p.saksbehandlerUhrPuMote_id
    where  b.status_id = 7
  ) as resultTable
  order by resultTable.dato desc
```

Comment: 1) My bad; It was HQL turned into SQL because of the UNION ALL. (I've changed the text to SQL)

Comment: 2) Actually, it seems I need to write each field of Forslag in line 1, as select id, name, ...  etc, in order to avoid the b.dato among them.  Not so elegant, but solves the problem.

Comment: @ThorHovden: Hi, yes, exactly, if you want to manage field positions you do manually.